# Do any programming languages support the ≥ character, Unicode U+2265, to mean greater than or equal to?

Tags: unicode, comparison-operators

It is common in programming to use something like `>=` as the comparison operator meaning "is greater than or equal to".  Unicode includes at least one specific character that represents this concept: ≥ (U+2265).  Are there any programming languages that accept this character for use as a comparison operator?

Note: There probably exist programming languages in which a user can define `≥` as a comparison operator.  That's certainly interesting, but I am asking about cases where the base language, some standard distribution of it, or some widely used package or library already has it so defined.

Comment: Yes, AppleScript is one.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/cascadia-code#powerline-and-programming-ligatures

Comment: Oldest computer languages used symbols for most operations and statements. It is just slow to type on modern keyboards, so now we have e.g. Fira font which can visually convert >= into ≥, etc. and some IDE support this font with such ligatures. -- But your question may be interesting, and about new "Unicode attacks".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you would find a comprehensive list of languages that support Unicode operators. One of the most well known is [Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/), which is typically used for computational analysis.

[image: julia sample code]

There are a few others, like Perl 6 (now known as [Raku](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#___top)) which has some support for it, along with Scala.

Many modern languages support Unicode in identifiers but do not natively implement Unicode operators. It's largely unnecessary since most IDEs also support font-ligatures: a feature that renders operators like `>=` as `≥`.

[image: RubyMine font ligatures]